# Handling certain events from another class

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with a class that has the following function:

```
Private _players As New List(Of Player)

Public Sub PlayerAdd(ByVal name As String, ByVal money As Decimal)
        _players.Add(New Player With {
                     .name = name,
                     .money = money})
    End Sub
```

When this sub is called, from a different class, I want to be able to catch this event and run other code like this:

```
Public foo As New MyCustomClass

Private Sub test Handles foo.PlayerAdded
' Code I want to run here.
End Sub
```

I know that I cannot do this like that, however it is just to show what I am trying to accomplish. What would be the best way to do something like this?

Comment: There is no event to handle.  If you want to handle an event then you need to declare an event for a start, then you need to raise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as follow:

```
Public Class MyCustomClass

    Private _players As New List(Of Player)
    Public Event PlayerAdded()

    Public Sub PlayerAdd(ByVal name As String, ByVal money As Decimal)
        _players.Add(New Player With {
                 .name = name,
                 .money = money})
        RaiseEvent PlayerAdded()
    End Sub

End Class
```

And you can catech that event from the other class:

```
AddHandler foo.PlayerAdded, AddressOf <SomeSub> ' To catch the event
```

Comment: Does it matter where I put the `AddHandler` or is it fine if I just put it in a form's `Load` event for example.

Comment: Yes you can put it in the form Load event, but make sure to put it after you declare your foo object.